# A reminder to those with 500+ reputation: please remember your close/reopen votes!

Tags: discussion, close-votes, reopen-votes

<sup>This was originally an old announcement, but still relevant today for different reasons.</sup>

On this public beta site, every user with 500+ reputation [has the ability](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to help with closing and reopening questions, which is important as it helps to keep off-topic or unanswerable questions off the site while making sure on-topic ones can be answered. There are currently [117 such users](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users?page=4&tab=reputation&filter=all), but only [a small handful of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/literature/query/1254323/close-voters?numberOfDays=365) have participating in closing any questions in the last 365 days. This situation is especially worrying since two of the most active close-voters have recently been elected moderators, which makes us more hesitant to cast close votes since they are now binding.

**May I remind all 500+ rep users to please continue using these powers when necessary.** Please remember to check the [Close](https://literature.stackexchange.com/review/close) and [Reopen](https://literature.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) review queues regularly, and be conscientious about voting to close new questions if they shouldn't be here and voting to reopen closed questions which have been substantially improved or shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

---

<sup>Below is the original text of this post from 2017.</sup>

Literature SE has [just entered public beta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/17) - yay! - which means a lot of the [reputation thresholds for site privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/278659) have changed. Specifically, the one whose threshold has changed the most is the ability to **vote to close and reopen other people's posts**.

Up until this point, *every*one has been able to cast close/reopen votes. Every single user, even those totally new to SE with just 1 reputation point. Now that privilege has suddenly been restricted only to users with 500+ reputation - currently [29 of us](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). Of course this number (of users able to VTC/VTRO) will grow rapidly, but it will take a long long time to become quite as large as it was yesterday.

Comment: I want to suggest one thing, give OP advice to improve his or her question before you vote to close. If OP improves the question enough, you might not need to vote to close.

Comment: What about who don't have 500 rep ;)

Comment: @TheBitByte Giving advice on improving the question is always a good idea, but it doesn't necessarily have to be before you vote to close. If the question does get put on hold and then improved, it automatically enters the Reopen Votes review queue and can swiftly be reopened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to the [32 users who can VTC](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), all users with 15 or more can *flag* for closure.

This will put the post in the Close Votes queue, where more users with the Close privilege will be able to see that it needs to be closed.

[image]