# Literature is graduating on December 16th, 2021!

Tags: discussion

All of your hard work has paid off: We're officially graduating!

The Community Managers have confirmed that as part of their ongoing work on site lifecycles, **as of December 16, 2021, Literature.SE will be leaving Beta**.

What does this mean for us, practically?

Practically? Almost nothing. We'll be losing the "Beta" label in our site name, no longer marking us as a site that's in development. We will potentially have the option to open up migration paths for questions.

We are *not* going to be adjusting the reputation thresholds for privileges; that will happen at some point in the future when the site deems it necessary. It's not coupled to graduation anymore.
We will also not be getting a site design at this stage, unfortunately; site designs have been paused for several years now and there is not currently a timeline on when they'll be available for other sites.

As part of graduation, there *will* be a full-fledged moderator election at some point in 2022 or 2023 (we do not have a date currently; there are a lot of sites coming out of Beta at the same time, so it depends on the backlog of site elections in the next year). Any current pro-tem moderators - including myself - who want to remain moderators will have to run again, and any community members who wish to run for moderator will also be able to at that time. We'll keep you posted when we have more of an idea what the timeline is for that.

---

I'd like to take this opportunity to thank all the people who've been involved in bringing the site to this point. My original co-mods @user111 and @Slate; my current co-mods @Gallifreyan, @Rand al'Thor, and @Tsundoku; all the users who write excellent questions and answers on the main site; all the people who've taken a hand in helping with the upkeep and moderation of the site; and the Community Managers who've been there behind the scenes for the past almost five years. Each and every one of you has made a difference to this site, and to me personally. Thank you.

I'm excited to see the site move into the next stage of its existence, and I hope to see you all come along for the ride.

Comment: I assume we will also lose the "Site Stats" on the home page. Those disappeared from the sites that graduated in 2019.

Comment: @Tsundoku We'll probably also lose the live stats on Area 51: they'll be frozen at their final values and it'll say "At the end of beta, this site had ..."

Comment: To celebrate this moment the community or at least someone should write a book on the history of Literature.SE . :D (This comment is 100% a joke.)

Answer (score 7):

### Yay, we're graduated!

I'm a sucker for data, so I wanted to record the exact state of various site statistics at the moment of graduation.

---

- Our top **authors**, by number of questions in the respective author tags, are:

  1. [william-shakespeare](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare) (217 questions)
  2. [j-r-r-tolkien](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) (89 questions)
  3. [ayn-rand](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayn-rand) (76 questions)
  4. [george-orwell](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-orwell) (71 questions)
  5. [c-s-lewis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-s-lewis) (57 questions)
  6. [tomasz-jedrowski](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomasz-jedrowski) (56 questions)
  7. [arthur-conan-doyle](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthur-conan-doyle) (49 questions)
  8. [thomas-hardy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thomas-hardy) and [neil-gaiman](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neil-gaiman) (47 questions each)
  9. [helen-garner](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helen-garner) (43 questions)
  10. [lord-byron](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-byron) (42 questions)
  11. [fyodor-dostoyevsky](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fyodor-dostoyevsky) and [j-k-rowling](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-k-rowling) and [charles-dickens](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charles-dickens) (38 questions each)
  12. [g-k-chesterton](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-k-chesterton) (37 questions)
  13. [f-scott-fitzgerald](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-scott-fitzgerald) (35 questions)
  14. [edgar-allan-poe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edgar-allan-poe) and [james-joyce](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-joyce) (33 questions each)
  15. [homer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homer) and [agatha-christie](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agatha-christie) (32 questions each)
  16. [t-s-eliot](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-s-eliot) and [jane-austen](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jane-austen) (31 questions each)

---

- Our top non-English **languages**, by number of questions in the respective language tags, are:

  1. French (170 questions)
  2. Russian (124 questions)
  3. German (90 questions)
  4. Greek (64 questions)
  5. Spanish (62 questions)
  6. Italian (45 questions)
  7. Japanese (42 questions)
  8. Persian (30 questions)
  9. Chinese (26 questions)
  10. Latin (23 questions)
  11. Bengali and Scandinavian (22 questions each)
  12. Portuguese (21 questions)
  13. Polish (19 questions)
  14. Belarusian (18 questions)
  15. Hebrew and Dutch (14 questions each)
  16. Hindi and Arabic (13 questions each)
  17. Akkadian and Korean (12 questions each)
  18. Urdu (9 questions)

---

- Our top **individual works**, by number of questions in the respective work tags (noting that this excludes short stories and poems according to tagging policy), are:

  1. [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings) (65 questions)
  2. [atlas-shrugged](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atlas-shrugged) (58 questions)
  3. [swimming-in-the-dark](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming-in-the-dark) (56 questions)
  4. [nineteen-eighty-four](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nineteen-eighty-four) and [sherlock-holmes](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes) (45 questions each)
  5. [the-childrens-bach](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-childrens-bach) (43 questions)
  6. [the-chronicles-of-narnia](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-narnia) (41 questions)
  7. [harry-potter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) and [macbeth](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbeth) (36 questions each)
  8. [hamlet](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamlet) (32 questions)
  9. [the-great-gatsby](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-great-gatsby) (30 questions)

---

- According to the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/alltime/literature), we have the following numbers of users above certain reputation thresholds:

  [image]

---

- The **most prolific posters**, according to the now-frozen [Area 51 statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top), are:

  - All posts: [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (**911** posts), [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) (**806** posts), [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) (**520** posts), [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica) (**299** posts), [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithical) (**233** posts), [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/verbose) (**225** posts), [Spagirl](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/333/spagirl) (**209** posts), [Matt Thrower](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/129/matt-thrower) (**164** posts), [Sean Duggan](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/96/sean-duggan) (**118** posts), [Peter Shor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1152/peter-shor) (**115** posts), [Ahmed Samir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10010/ahmed-samir) (**109** posts), [bobble](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11259/bobble) (**101** posts).
  - Questions: [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (**477** questions), [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) (**288** questions), [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica) (**225** questions), [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithical) (**172** questions), [Ahmed Samir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10010/ahmed-samir) (**108** questions), [Knight](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/8723/knight-wants-loong-back) (**91** questions), [Pasta Addict](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/4253/pasta-addict) (**78** questions), [Benjamin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/143/benjamin) (**63** questions), [Gallifreyan](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11/gallifreyan) (**55** questions).
  - Answers: [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) (**518** answers), [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) (**472** answers), [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (**434** answers), [Spagirl](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/333/spagirl) (**208** answers), [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/verbose) (**202** answers), [Matt Thrower](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/129/matt-thrower) (**118** answers), [Peter Shor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1152/peter-shor) (**109** answers).

---

- The detailed [Area 51 statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) are:

  - **5.7** questions per day (average over the two weeks 2-16 December 2021)
  - **78%** answered (1145 unanswered of 5124 questions overall)
  - **498** avid users (200+ reputation) and **10,068** total users
  - **1.4** answers per question (presumably this only counts answered questions)
  - **4151** visits per day (I don't know what period this is averaged over)